# constructor of FragmentPagerAdapter is undefined

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` that hosts a `viewPager`, i created the `FragmentPagerAdapter` in a different package. in the `fragment`.java file when i tried to call

```
adapter = new ViewPagerTabsAdapter(getFragmentManager(), fragList);
```

eclipses underscores that line with red squiggle and say

the constructor ViewPagerTabsAdapter(FragmentManager, List) is undefined

i think it is because of the imports i used, but i do not know how to solve it,

please find the code with the imports posted below:

**frag3**:

```
import com.example.fragmentcommunication_00.adapter.ViewPagerTabsAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;
....
....

private void initViews(View root) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    vPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.frag3_pager);       
    actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    adapter = new ViewPagerTabsAdapter(getFragmentManager(), fragList);
}
```

** ViewPagerTabsAdapter**:

```
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class ViewPagerTabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

List<Fragment> mFragList;

public ViewPagerTabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> mFragList) {
    super(fm);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.mFragList = mFragList;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mFragList.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.mFragList.size();
}
```

}

**Update_2**:
the imports are as follows and in frag3 the `fragList.add` is undefined and `getSupportFragmentManager()` is undefined as well. and in the `adapter` one of the methods its signature looks like this:

```
@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

now my imports in the `adapter` are :

```
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
```

and imports in `Frag3` are :

```
   import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;
import com.example.fragmentcommunication_00.adapter.ViewPagerTabsAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getSupportFragmentManager` instead because your constructor receives an `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` and `getFragmentManager` returns `android.app.FragmentManager` instead

Comment: now when i use "getSupportFragmentManager", i receive: it is not defined in the type frag3

Comment: You have to decide if you want to you use support fragments (v4) or not. It seems you have multiple/different types of fragments. `getSupportFragmentManager` can only be called from a `FragmentActivity`. If you don't use a `FragmentActivity` then change your `ViewPagerTabsAdapter` to use `android.app.FragmentManager` instead

Comment: can you please have a lokk at the update section above

Comment: `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter`... Once again... that's v4...

Comment: Like I said `getSupportFragmentManager` is only available on `FragmentActivity`. Change your frag3 to be a `FragmentActivity` instead.

Comment: ok, but when i change frag3 to extend Fragmentactivity some lifeCycles callbacks are not available, like onattach()??

Comment: I will only say this one more time. Decide if you want to use support fragments (with fragment activity) or normal fragments. If you have to change your whole code to use the support library then use Fragment instead. You don't seem to know the difference between them both.

Answer (score 0):

in fag3 try replacing
import android.app.Fragment;
with
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: now, adapter imports are : "
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;"

Comment: and and fra3 imports are: "
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.example.fragmentcommunication_00.adapter.ViewPagerTabsAdapter;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

Comment: there should be one getItem method inside PagerAdapter class

Comment: yes understandable, but the return type is the one i am talking about, it is not a fragment